# Are we allowed to apply the FTC2 to an integrable function on an open interval?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Consider the function

$$f(x)=1, \text{ for } x\neq ...-2,-1,1,2,...$$

[image]

I believe we can show that $f$ is integrable on any interval, thus $$F(x)=\int_a^x f$$ is continuous.

Are we allowed to apply the second fundamental theorem of calculus with $f$ on an interval such as $[1,2]$? Ie, can we say $\int_1^2 f = F(2)-F(1)$?

The statement of the theorem seems to  be that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f=g'$ for some function $g$ then $\int_a^b f =g(b)-g(a)$

Now, $f$ is integrable on $[1,2]$ but is not defined at $1$ and $2$, though for all points in $(1,2)$, $f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)=\int_1^x h$.

Comment: If by "integrable" you mean properly Riemann/Lebesgue integrable, then $f$ is not integrable on any interval containing a nonzero integer.  The story is different if improper integration is also considered.

Comment: By "integrable" I am referring to a definition I saw in Ch. 13 of Spivak's Calculus, which is that a function $f$ which is bounded on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if $\sup\{L(f,P)\}=\inf\{U(f,P)\}$, where $L(f,P)$ is the lower sum of $f$ for a partition $P$, $U(f,P)$ is the upper sum.

Comment: How can you meaningfully define a lower sum or an upper sum at a point where the function itself is not defined?

Comment: To let $f$ be **integrable** on $[a,b]$, $f$ at least should be *defined* on the whole closed interval $[a,b]$. Otherwise, we cannot even talk about **integrable**.

Comment: @SuzuHirose you tell me: why can we not do it? A lower sum, for example, is defined $L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(t_i-t_{i-1})$, where $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, and $m_i=\inf\{f(x):t_{i-1}\leq x\leq t_i\}$

Comment: How if $f$ defined on the integers?

Comment: @copper.hat the question says that $f$ is not defined on the integers, in the last paragraph. That's why various commenters have been pointing out this doesn't make sense since all of the things evianpring is putting in to the equations aren't defined either.

Comment: @evianpring You seem to assume that $\inf\{f(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\}$ automatically means $\inf\{f(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i \text{ and $x$ is in the domain of $f$}\}$, which it does not; in fact, it is simply undefined if any $x \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]$ is outside the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is not defined at certain points it does not make any sense at all to claim it to be integrable over a range containing those points, any more than we can ask what the value of $1/x$ is at $x=0$.