# Does this function $h$ qualify as odd, and for $H(x)=\int_a^x h$ can we prove $H(x)=H(-x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

Consider the following function

$$h(x)=\begin{cases} [x], \text{ for } x\geq0 \text{ and } x\neq 1,2,3,... \\ [x]+1, \text{ for } x<0 \text{ and } x\neq -1,-2,-3,... \end{cases}$$

I believe the graph looks like this

[image]

I believe we can say that $h$ is integrable ([though this seems unclear to me and there seems to be disagreement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497832/are-we-allowed-to-apply-the-ftc2-to-an-integrable-function-on-an-open-interval/4497840#4497840)), and therefore $H(x)=\int_a^x h$ is continuous.

Note that with the exception of $0$, the integers are not in the domain of $h$.

Note that for any number in the domain we can write

$$h(x)=-h(-x)\tag{1}$$

**Question 1: Does this qualify $h$ as an odd function?**

Now, ultimately, I'd like to show $H(x)=H(-x)$ for all $x$.

To this end, are we allowed to integrate each side of $(1)$ from $0$ to $x$?

If we are, are we allowed to split the integrals into integrals on the intervals $[0,1]$, $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$, ...,$[[x],x]$?

Finally, if we can split them, can we apply the FTC2 to each of the integrals?

This last question is: are we allowed to apply FTC2 to $h$ on an open interval such as $[1,2]$? Ie, is

$$\int_1^2 h(x)dx=H(2)-H(1)$$

?

If the answer to these questions were yes then we would have, for $g(x)=-h(-x)$

$$\int_0^x h(x)dx=\int_0^x (-h(-x))dx=\int_0^x g$$

$$\int_0^1 h + \int_1^2 h \int_2^3 h + ... + \int_{[x]}^x h = \int_0^1 g + \int_1^2 g \int_2^3 g + ... + \int_{[x]}^x g$$

$$H(x)-H(0)=H(-x)-H(0)$$

$$H(x)=H(-x)$$

Okay, so at this point I can already feel the wrath coming my way for even having conceived of this atrocity.

The result sure does seem to be intuitively true. But is the proof a failure?

Comment: You can't say $h$ is integrable without defining $h$ at the integers as well. At least, if you want to use the Darboux (Spivak) definition of integrability.

Comment: In that case the entire endeavor above is useless because $h$ is supposed to represent a derivative.

Comment: I don't see why that matters. A derivative of a function is still a function. It doesn't get special treatment to be considered integrable.

Comment: "*function $h$ qualify as odd*" $\,-\,$ Yes, it is an odd function on its domain, which by your definition is $\,\mathbb R \setminus \big(\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}\big)\,$. $\;$ "*we can say that $h$ is integrable*" $\;-\;$ The [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Terminology_and_notation) of $h$ is only defined for intervals within its domain, so $h$ is *not* integrable on any interval that includes points where it is not defined i.e. any interval that includes a non-zero integer. For intervals which do *not* include a non-zero integer, $h$ is constant, thus trivially integrable.

Comment: If we redefine $h$ such that $h(x)=[x]$ for $x\geq 0$ and $h(x)=[x]+1$ for $x<0$ and $x\neq -1,-2,-3,...$, and $h(x)=[x]-1$ for $x=-1,-2,-3,...$, then $h$ is again odd on its domain which is now $\mathbb{R}$. Is $h$ now integrable? In this case, does the rest of the argument fail?

Comment: The point I am trying to get at here is that maybe a function $H$ doesn't have to be differentiable everywhere for us to be able to conclude that it is even, based on the additional information that the function representing the derivative (wherever it is actually defined) is odd (we may have to add a few points to make it defined everywhere)

Comment: "*a function $H$ doesn't have to be differentiable everywhere for us to be able to conclude that it is even*" $\;-\;$ Of course it doesn't have to be differentiable. There are plenty of even functions which are not differentiable, take for example $f(x) = |x|$. $\;$ "*based on the additional information that the function representing the derivative (wherever it is actually defined) is odd*" $\;-\;$ Of course that if the derivative (exists and) is odd on only a strict subset of the domain of the function, that doesn't imply that the function must be even. Don't know why you'd think it did.

Comment: @dxiv If the derivative is odd on its whole domain, then $f$ does have to be even (on the domain of its derivative).

Comment: Not sure if this is true, but it seems that if the derivative is odd on the whole domain then it must be continuous. Otherwise, it would be discontinuous at some point and thus couldn't be a derivative at that point.

Comment: @politeproofs No, why?

Comment: @politeproofs I think the conclusion reached about that in a separate question is that $f$ has to be differentiable for that result to hold. The point of my current question is to see if its possible to relax that assumption to any degree. I am sort of suggesting with my example above that maybe there could be weaker restrictions.

Comment: @dxiv Suppose $-f'(x) = f'(-x)$. Define $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$ and so $g'(x) = f'(x) + f'(-x) = 0$, so $g(0) = 0$, which implies that $g(x) = 0$, and so $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: @politeproofs $\,$ "*so $g′(x)=f′(x)+f′(−x)=0$, so $g(0)=0$*" $\;$ That's assuming $0$ is in the domain of $f'$. Think of obvious counterexamples when it's not, since this is what my previous comment was about.